# Array Flattening arrays of matrices given by rules

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, list-manipulation

Fix an $n$ and an $m$ positive integers.I have some set of four $n\times n$ matrices $A$,$B$,$Y$,$Z$ (where $Z$ is the zero matrix). I'd like to input the $nm\times nm$ matrix of block matrices given by

```
ArrayFlatten [{{A,B,Z,...,Z},{Y,A,B,Z,...,Z}{Z,Y,A,B,Z...},...,{Z,...,Z,Y,A}}]
```

I have tried to do this using `SparseArray` using something like

```
SparseArray[{
  {i_, i_} -> A,
  {i_, j_} /; i - j == 1 -> B,
  {i_, j_} /; j - i == 1 -> Y,
  {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] > 1 -> Z
 }, {m, m}]
```

`SparseArray` does not seem to play nice with matrix inputs, and I do not think it is the right tool. I am told that things are not lists. What is an easy way to build block matrices out of rules (as Sparse Array does for matrices of numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n=2;

A = ConstantArray[1, {n, n}];
B = ConstantArray[2, {n, n}];
Y = ConstantArray[3, {n, n}];
Z = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];

ClearAll[a, b, y, z]

m = 10;

mat=Normal@SparseArray[{{i_,i_}->a,{i_,j_}/;i-j==1->b,{i_,j_}/;j-i 1->y,{i_,j_}/;Abs[i-j]>1->z},{m,m}]

ArrayFlatten[mat /. {a -> A, b -> B, y -> Y, z -> Z}]
```

Comment: So the only thing different here is that you defined $A,B,Y,Z$ after defining the matrix and the use of Normal(is that necessary?)? I am not in a position to check that this works yet, but could you explain why it does?

Comment: @PVAL I have edited my code.

Comment: This certainly works. I am not sure why my original method doesn't. Thanks very much anyway.

Comment: @PVAL `SparseArray` cannot insert matrices as elements. Lower case $a, b, y, z$ are only placeholders for $A, B, Y, Z$ and inside `ArrayFlatten` I replace them by rules.